# playframework org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, h2

I am trying to set up application with playframework 2.2 with JPA and H2 database.
I went with this:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJPA
and computer-database-jpa sample project

I AM GETTING AN ERROR:

```
 org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.
```

when I run my project I am getting that error:

---

> STACK TRACE

---

```
        --- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] play - datasource [jdbc:h2:mem:SupraCIRS] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:SupraCIRS
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.MedicalIncident
[error] application - 

! @6gh420nj2 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/incydent_medyczny/zapisz] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.MedicalIncident]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.MedicalIncident
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at models.MedicalIncident.toDataBase(MedicalIncident.java:40) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.MedicalIncidents.submit(MedicalIncidents.java:41) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.MedicalIncident
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:853) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:831) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
-

-- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /home/daniel/play-2.2.1/SupraCIRS/target/scala-2.10/classes...

[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/daniel/play-2.2.1/SupraCIRS/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] play - datasource [jdbc:h2:mem:play] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:play
[error] application - 

! @6gh36abca - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:148) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:35) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: models.MedicalIncident
        at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:665) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3533) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3487) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1376) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]


    //end
```

here is class that handle form submission in controller

```
    /**
 * Handle the form submission.
 */
@Transactional
public static Result submit() {
    Form<MedicalIncident> filledForm = MedicalIncidentForm.bindFromRequest();

    if(filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(form.render(filledForm));
    } else {
        MedicalIncident created = filledForm.get();
        //return ok(confirmation.render("Twój incydent został zgłoszony poprawnie."));
        created.save();
        return ok(summary.render(created));
    }
}
```

Here is my  model class

```
    package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.validation.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
import play.api.db.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Entity
public class MedicalIncident   {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String month;

    @Required
    public String place;

    @Required
    public String unit;

    @Required
    public String incident_type;

    @Required
    public int age;



    /**
     * Insert this new incident submission.
     */
    public void toDataBase() {
        JPA.em().persist(this);
    }



}
```

Plese help me

Comment: I've removed list from MedicalIncident class in model.
ANd error doesnt show up again.

Now I have this error when submitting the form

     [PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.MedicalIncident]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stack trace I presume you haven't put an @Id annotation on any fields in the MedicalIncident class but as you haven't posted it I can't be sure.

Hibernate requires an @Id field to uniquely identify a record.

[See hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity).

Comment: I've posted whole class. I hope it will be easier now. I've added @id annotation. But still the same

Comment: Is it still the same stack trace or has that changed at all?